# Вывести слова в которых нет буквы 'e'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    string s="We study C++ programming language first semester.", word;
    
    s.pop_back();
 
    stringstream in(s);
    while (in >> word)
    {
        if (word.find('e') == std::string::npos)
        cout << word << "\n";            
    }
    
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Всем привет! Дано строку "We study C++ programming language first semester.". И надо вывести с нее слова в которых нет буквы 'e'.

Есть такой вариант программы, но хотелось бы как то чтоли по проще, возможно с *char* а не *string* может у кого есть еще какие варианты?? Буду очень благодарен всем за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а куда проще то?

если вы не хотите использовать stl, то алгоритм будет такой:

1. идем по строке от позиции_в_строке 0 до позиции_в_строке конца строки
2. если буква не пробел

2.1) заносим букву в буфер по позиции_в_буфере

2.2) увеличиваем поцизию_в_буфере на 1

2.3) если буква - `е` - выставляем флаг_буквы на true

3. если буква пробел или позиции_в_строке - конец строки:

3.1) заносим в буфер '\0'

3.2) если флаг_буквы - false и позицию_в_буфере больше 1 (чтобы на пробелы не срабатывать, формируя пустые строки) - выводим буфер на экран

3.3) выставляем флаг_буквы в false

3.4) выставляем позицию_в_буфере в 0

Comment: Спасибо, а как заносить букву в буфер

Comment: буфер - массив - вы можете его создать размером больше, чем у первоначальной строки (ну чтобы наверняка), а заносите как и все остальное` `my_buffer[pos_buffer++] = letter`